# how to overlap a list of menus over an image

Tags: css

When the menu "product" is clicked or mouse over, the another list of menus appear.. but the image block which is below the menu bar, moves away from the position. if i use css [ position:absolute;], then the image box remains static and the product's sub-menu overlaps the image block, which is what i wanted. but the image blocks width & height settings change drastically, thereby spoiling the alignment.
 pls chk the codings in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2YXp/)

```css
.home_menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 98%;
  height: 3.3%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
div#menuDemo {
  clear: both;
  //border:1px solid black;
  height: 78%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #A55927;
  /*Remove this next one in production - Used for demo purpose only*/
  margin-bottom: 0.1%;
  padding-top: 0.7%;
  z-index: 4;
}
div#menuDemo ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #A55927;
}
div#menuDemo > ul > li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
div#menuDemo ul li {
  width: 25%;
  //border: 5px solid purple;

}
div#menuDemo ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}
div#menuDemo > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div#menuDemo > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.sub1 {
  width: 100%;
  //border:1px solid green;

}
.colouring {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.colour {
  //border:1px solid blue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  //width:100%;

}
.wrapper {
  border: 5px solid pink;
  width: 98.8%;
  height: 82%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.uniform_block {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.uniform_block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="home_menu">
    <div id="menuDemo">
      <ul>
        <li id="homeMenu"><a href="#menuHome" class="colour">About Us</a>
        </li>

        <!--  <li ><a href="#menuHome" class="colour">About Us</a></li> -->

        <li><a href="#" class="colour" id="expand">Products</a>
          <ul class="sub1">
            <li> <a href="#" class="colouring"> Uniforms </a>
              <ul>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> &nbsp;&nbsp </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Automobile&nbsp;Industry&nbsp;Uniforms </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Pharmaceutical&nbsp;Uniforms </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Food&nbsp;Industry&nbsp;Uniforms </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Government&nbsp;Sector&nbsp;Uniforms </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> School/College&nbsp;Uniforms </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> &nbsp;&nbsp </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="colouring">Shoes</a>
              <ul>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> &nbsp;&nbsp </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Industrial&nbsp;Shoes </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Safety&nbsp;&&nbsp;Security&nbsp;Shoes </a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> Executive&nbsp;Shoes</a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="colour"> &nbsp;&nbsp </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="colour">Contact Us</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="uniform_block">
      <img src=" http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSH-kRi3rkVciPcH_c6dDJJI6C1ntzwcKl9MoVQIyuKk8F7unpf" />
    </div>
    <div class="home_footer">
      <div class="footer_contents"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

kindly help. My requirement is, when i mouse over the "product menu", the drop down menu should be viewed above the image block which is below the menu bar.

Comment: anything is editted in fiddle? pls help if possible. when i mouseover the "products" menu, its sub-menu's should not push away the image. instead it should be placed overlapping the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **position:absolute** to the css of your ul menu (in your case, the sub1 class), and remove the width:100% so it can inherit the default width of its parent. Absolute positioning will prevent your browser from trying to put your ul element after the previous element on the page.

```
ul.sub1 {
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2YXp/2/